# WooCommerce different product in cart on different page

Tags: woocommerce, product, checkout

I have two WooCommerce products and I want one of them loaded into the cart automatically when page A loads, and the other one loaded into the cart automatically when page B loads. My code checks the page ID and adds a specific product to the cart by product ID (after emptying the cart). Checkout is added via shortcodes to each page.

My problem is that regardless of whether I load page A or page B, when I get to the checkout I see the same product; the first product.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load' );
function bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load() {

   // product ID to add to cart

    $product_id = 1150;
    $product_id2 = 4792 ;

     if ( is_page( 3337 ) ) {    

      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id ); 
   }
      else if ( is_page( 4232 ) ) { 

      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id2 ); 
   }        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp', 'bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load' );
function bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load() {

   // product ID to add to cart

    $product_id = 1150;
    $product_id_1 = 4792 ;

     if ( is_page( 3337 ) ) {    

      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id ); 
   }
      else if ( is_page( 4232 ) ) { 

      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id_1 ); 
   }  
}
```